# Windows map file system

Tags: c++, winapi, dictionary, filesystems

Windows Explorer can associate a drive letter with a file system or directory within a file system. How do I do this from a C++ program under Windows 7 and Vista? My search of visual studio documentation and the web has not turned up API calls for doing this. Does anybody know?

Comment: How about launching net use from a system command? http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Here is an additional option: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6847/Map-Network-Drive-API

Comment: The api is WNetAddConnection2() with dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK.

Answer (score 2):

The [`SetVolumeMountPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function seems to do what you are after.

You'll find quite a lot of [related functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Disk Management, Volume Management, etc.) on MSDN (your best friend as a Windows developer, sometimes called "Microsoft Developer Network" or "Windows Dev Center").